# A text only PDF page using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating a multi-page PDF with different graphs in each page using matplotlib. I would like to add another page that contains some information relevant to these graphs. But all text addition methods I've seen in matplotlib so far, seem to require a figure to be present already. Is it possible to add a text only page in matplotlib?

Comment: you should be able to add an axes/subplot, hide the axis and add texts

Comment: If it's really a whole page, you'd probably be better off producing a test-only pdf separately, and then merging the two using eg pdftk.

Comment: You could set `text.usetex = True` and just dump a whole page of text through latex.